# Command to measure SNR ratio on an ad-hoc network

Tags: networking

I'm working on a project with Ubuntu 14.04 where I need to connect multiple Ubuntu devices on an ad-hoc network and measure the SNR ratio. I'm using the TP-LINK TL-WN7200ND USB wireless adaptors for this. I'm unable to find a command that would give me this ratio. 'iw dev wlan1 scan | grep signal' gives me a list of BSS mac id's which isn't what I'm looking for. Is there a better command for this?